# How to run multiple Flyway migrations in a single transaction?

Tags: flyway

I have multiple scripts that need to be run against a database. In my case it is an absolute non-feasible task to have the migration in one script per version.

However with the workaround that has been mentioned several times being, to make minor version scripts, this is too, not handed in a way I expect.
If I have 4 minor scripts that need to be run, I would expect to have all 4 in the same transaction. so if 4/4 fails, the previous 3 should roll back.

I am even more confused by this, and If I am upgrading a system from version 2 --> 4 and 3 passes, while 4 fails. I'm left in a sticky situation, of hoping the v3 rollbacks were good enough.

Am I missing something with the command line interface where I can tell flyway to migrate everything in a single transaction. Or to 'test' the migration and roll everything back allowing me to know if the migration will work without actually committing anything.

Edit

====Context====

I work in an environment with multiple full stack developers. Where we are constantly adding and changing features. Because of this we all have our own databases as well. Every change gets scripted, so that the changes can be applied to the database once the script is affecting our branch, or integration branches.

Because of this when going between multiple machines, there are multiple scripts per version.

It it not feasible to state that each developer must constantly be updating one given file. As it is also not wise to have development machines on a different version scheme to the staging and production databases. Not to mention the hell this would cause when merging branches.

Also when merging, if there is an issue that has come into play with the order of the scripts. The entire set should roll back, until a clean migration can occur.

We had our own migration tool, the only issue i'm facing is that it does not work in docker yet, and I was hoping to not have to change it.

Comment: I just had to change the title of your question for it to make sense as a technical question, rather than an opinion-based one. You're not really asking whether you're using Flyway wrong (that would not be a good question for SO). You're asking if you can run multiple scripts in the same transaction, and this *is* a good question to ask. I also removed the docker tag. Your question has nothing to do with Docker. The fact that your former migration tool did not work on Docker is anecdotal at best.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this wasn't possible when this question was posted, but now it is.
From the Flyway docs [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#transactions):

> you can also configure Flyway to wrap the entire execution of all migrations of a single migration run within a single transaction by setting the `group` property to `true`.

Answer (score -2):

I mean it's not possible with command line run is every scripts run in one transaction, but when you create one script then you may run in one transaction.

For example:

- Download flyway.

  ```
  wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-commandline/4.1.2/flyway-commandline-4.1.2-linux-x64.tar.gz
  ```
- Extract flyway (you must install java).

  ```
  tar zxvf flyway-commandline-4.1.2-linux-x64.tar.gz
  ```
- Go to flyway

  ```
  cd flyway-4.1.2
  ```
- Config in /conf/flyway.conf

  ```
  flyway.url=jdbc:h2:file:./foobardb
  flyway.user=SA
  flyway.password=
  ```
- Creating the empty migrations in the /sql directory called Vx__xxxxxx.sql

  ```
  select 1;
  ```
- Creating the migration with every migration in one script /sql Vlast_xxx.sql
  Who run in one transaction.

  ```
  create table ...; create table ..; create procedure ...;
  ```
- Run migration

  ```
  flyway-4.1.2> flyway migrate
  ```

In docker before command use RUN, I guess you know about it.

It's just a template but after few fixes, it may be fine.

Comment: This answer does *not* address the question being asked. The question is how to run different scripts in a single transaction and it states that it would be impractical to have it all in a single script. Also, the question is *not* about how to install Flyway.

Comment: The answer is that you can do it in one script.